# How do I redirect a GET with query string as a POST with formdata

Tags: http, redirect, servlets

Technologies in use:

1. Servlet 4.0 (provided by Tomcat 9)
2. Java 8

I am working with a commercial vendor's front end and am limited to sending GET requests from that front end.

There is information in the request that I do not want them to alter accidentally (and more than 1 user has so far) by changing the values in the query string of that request.

My idea was to redirect the GET request through a Servlet where I could remove the query string so they won't edit it, and submit it as a POST with **formdata** instead so that I can still get the data.

I cannot modify the page which sends the request, as it is vendor-provided software.

The query string with GET was previously done to get around this limitation, and if we had full control over this front end, we would simply change it to a POST with **formdata**.

Can I perform this redirect to avoid creating a more complicated landing page from the vendor's front end?

I've looked into forwarding, but that won't change the URL.
I've looked into sending a request from a page in the middle and returning the response, but that won't change the URL.
I've looked into Javascript embedded in a JSP that submits a hidden form, but that will possibly cause issues under load.

I'm hoping there is a simple way to redirect with a modified request object from inside a Servlet, but I haven't found anything.

example request from the user currently:

- method: GET
- URL: http://www.your.domain.com/service-get-or-post?field1=foo&field2=bar&field3=42

desired new target:

- method: GET
- URL: http://www.your.domain.com/service-trampoline?field1=foo&field2=bar&field3=42

desired new redirect:

- method: POST
- content: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- URL: http://www.your.domain.com/service-get-or-post
- body: field1=foo&field2=bar&field3=42

Comment: Not possible. You really need to redirect to a page which submits a hidden POST form using JavaScript. This is not a Java/Servlet limitation. This is a HTTP (and security) limitation. You'd have had exactly the same problem in any other web language/framework.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for the quick response. I figured it wasn't going to be possible when I couldn't find a single resource on how to change the method in any framework, except for P/R/G (and that has it's own response code) but I wanted to get confirmation before abandoning the approach all together.